# How do I add a .click() event to an image?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

I have a script that places an image based on a mouse click thanks to [Jose Faeti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701879/jose-faeti). Now I need help adding a .click() event to the code below so that when a user clicks the image it performs the function shown in the script.

```
<img src="http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/LDRYh.jpg" alt="unfinished bingo card" />.click()
```

I put the entire code below, in case you want to see it.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--

 document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

var img = document.createElement('img');

img.setAttribute('src', 'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png');

e.target.appendChild(img);
});

  // -->
 </script>

</head>

<body>
<img src="http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/LDRYh.jpg" alt="unfinished bingo card" />.click()
</body>
</html>
```

Help?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using jQuery? In any case, you're creating a DOM element for the image--adding a listener to that is the same as adding a listener to any other DOM element--which you already know how to do.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First of all, this line

```
<img src="http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/LDRYh.jpg" alt="unfinished bingo card" />.click()
```

You're mixing HTML and JavaScript. It doesn't work like that. Get rid of the `.click()` there.

If you read the JavaScript you've got there, `document.getElementById('foo')` it's looking for an HTML element with an ID of `foo`. You don't have one. Give your image that ID:

```
<img id="foo" src="http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/LDRYh.jpg" alt="unfinished bingo card" />
```

Alternatively, you could throw the JS in a function and put an onclick in your HTML:

```
<img src="http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/LDRYh.jpg" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="myfunction()" />
```

I suggest you do some reading up on JavaScript and HTML though.

---

The others are right about needing to move the `<img>` above the JS click binding too.

Answer (score 13):

You can't bind an event to the element before it exists, so you should do it in the `onload` event:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png');
    e.target.appendChild(img);
  });

};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="foo" src="http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/LDRYh.jpg" alt="unfinished bingo card" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Enclose `<img>` in `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com.pk"><img src="smiley.gif"></a>
```

it will open link on same tab, and if you want to open link on new tab then use target="_blank"

```
<a href="http://www.google.com.pk" target="_blank"><img src="smiley.gif"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" >
function openOnImageClick()
{
//alert("Jai Sh Raam");
// document.getElementById("images").src = "fruits.jpg";
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.setAttribute('src', 'tiger.jpg');
  img.setAttribute('width', '200');
   img.setAttribute('height', '150');
  document.getElementById("images").appendChild(img);


}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Screen Shot View</h1>
<p>Click the Tiger to display the Image</p>

<div id="images" >
</div>

<img src="tiger.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="openOnImageClick()" />
<img src="Logo1.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="openOnImageClick()" />

</body>
</html>
```