# Pop-up text on image click WordPress

Tags: wordpress, toggle, elementor, popup

I am designing a wordpress site for a friend. He wants the bio text to appear after clicking on necessary image. I noticed this is straight forward with Elementor Pro. I want to keep things free for him at the mo.
I am running the Astra theme with basic Elementor. I also know how to code so if you think this is a custom css job then let me know the work around. (I'm brand new to WP)
Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been researching on YouTube. TC-Team members plugin might work. Will start there

Comment: elementor supports pretty photo and an option like open in popup, you can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an onclick event to the image and write some java script to add text where you want or may be enable a hidden textarea ??

You can check this link below for reference

[How do I add a .click() event to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374562/how-do-i-add-a-click-event-to-an-image)