# How to make an image as a clickable link to another html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the JavaScript code I wrote **:**

```
var goToSecondPage= document.querySelector('.mobile');

goToSecondPage.addEventListener("click", function() {

document.location.href='productDetails.html';
 })
```

I'm trying to use an image in an existed class on an index html page (called mobile) and make it as a clickable link image to another html file called `productDetails.html`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a .click() event to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374562/how-do-i-add-a-click-event-to-an-image)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't wrap the `<img />` in an `<a>`? (i.e. Do you control the HTML or not? If you do, then just add a `<a>` in the HTML and skip scripting entirely - that way users using keyboard-navigation can navigate, as well as middle-clicking for opening in a new tab, as well as supporting users with JS disabled, etc.

Comment: Can you add the HTML to your question as a [mcve], please?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where your `productDetails.html` file is located. If it's in the root directory try

```js
var goToSecondPage = document.querySelector('.mobile');

goToSecondPage.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.location.pathname = '/productDetails.html';
});
```

This will only change your path, not the entire url.